# Moving Git project has caused many blob and tree errors

Tags: git, compiler-errors, migration

After moving my whole project folder from one location on a hard drive, to another on the same hard drive, `git fsck` now outputs the errors below. I did not change anything in the *.git* directory. Is this normal and how can I begin to fix this?

I don't really care if I have to reset the entire project and lose my history at this point! I would have imagined Git would work in my folder relatively. Is this not the case?

Rechecking out is not an option, because I have quite a bit of uncommitted work now.

```
broken link from    tree 20472cbdb5e63ca43e533765cc1a91625fe52972
              to    tree c40b8ac97a9afa0893ac6f10324848eb3a4cc460
broken link from    tree 99bba11042f2c2342b2a32e12483b16e6c46ca8b
              to    tree bbb9d8714d49586842fb141e5c3da6fb7cc90488
broken link from    tree 010f020814c6a991a927eeae696ddd7ea928b4db
              to    tree bb3aacd59b6f876f7213a466c94a32d6e1049020
broken link from    tree 952eb80d9f0414b7dc4adf0c8b86ebf9373f3a30
              to    blob bb345fdd2f7ab26ca7fa7ab714d3279e445ca934
broken link from    tree 5906b6d79b7faf30a2461729de694e465a5bf4c1
              to    blob c44110ff88641d5c14327ca7b00f5a76ff8e2228
broken link from    tree 0114e32779714a4b1c4419fa6a6be1fc04265960
              to    blob bb98c60ea1b96a838fe497742b9223ccd97abcc5
broken link from    tree 80bdd30b648cf3f4156ae12b88f12d36dd66909a
              to    blob bb14ba97547dfd68af6c6eba3bbd74416b9d683f
broken link from    tree 2307fc0c1604b3336cba6622420c3632906ec063
              to    blob bbeb6d9170b74545a8a20ec11fd049a86d7f313e
broken link from    tree 9a74b5fb00161ae220e93b3cc2e45eff7fcedef9
              to    blob c457fb4c4ea3758bcf10599b7d93d6202e195d3e
broken link from    tree 13cdd163fb9d7aaf00c03b19b07ec7f316959f2a
              to    blob bb50cb721e30ea8759089e8dd37cb79728c58651
broken link from    tree 3873530bd6cb79d7a1fc42da1fc0fe493fb0e892
              to    tree c4995cff4851c8577bf6702635c0f760b4f59627
broken link from    tree f9f1ee36c894aaed76ddb90cf91ebd3700bcb384
              to    blob bb2a3fc65c38168a96b6e2baae6b7adffa812597
broken link from    tree c8684f6dee7f94a2db6bec1a245655417138dcf4
              to    tree c481208829c1275cc4d5dd1ef316f2e2832234ca
broken link from    tree 10c06ab1c21ee71643f8884efe62f5e35abe418e
              to    blob c46859a5137b04e6342147b6780f927089ccb8e7
broken link from    tree 10c06ab1c21ee71643f8884efe62f5e35abe418e
              to    blob c405c0acde50fbcc3ba240b105d88fc18256a605
broken link from    tree a0d2467fcae809a5a5ef5dbbe67aec7f27d32c2b
              to    blob c430db086cc4d0881642e07d630352b83c0026cd
broken link from    tree 07f04871d7419bd219effe60705e1a45b724677f
              to    blob bb61249cfb3d2470572911b68d920abd77dcad2e
broken link from    tree 07f04871d7419bd219effe60705e1a45b724677f
              to    blob c4cff0e29bc5a7dcd62d6b17e91a0e24c5af5025
broken link from    tree 07f04871d7419bd219effe60705e1a45b724677f
              to    blob c45bf78c96a972a88d79d927a1fba5ade6b197b1
broken link from    tree 115ab71506fa63ef9d64f34aa4fb30c0becbdbcc
              to    blob bb0ba653563b50784ec57785e189246a75e51e8b
broken link from    tree 67cbaec51d0cfec5500602015e49b5488095c1bc
              to    blob c44eed79d1a98f2fe65c5b1dd9deb86827624089
broken link from    tree 67cbaec51d0cfec5500602015e49b5488095c1bc
              to    blob bbb83d859655f7687f2a5fb224a6ce42de07fc24
broken link from    tree 2afc3b88e4d79749b61bafbd0ddf8e00725fbf3d
              to    blob bb5a95e6a741ff71d40e57e3341ad9d47d1d6831
broken link from    tree 2afc3b88e4d79749b61bafbd0ddf8e00725fbf3d
              to    blob bba0871d6353dc62f105c757978d224f8c224c03
broken link from    tree 2afc3b88e4d79749b61bafbd0ddf8e00725fbf3d
              to    blob bb69d9a0778058e7a5c6f872846659189e998f25
broken link from    tree cca2bf1e2189c6362b74ca0cd3538d7d8eb45c4d
              to    blob bbb1c50ed0a66a3291088beb722f652fa39f6285
missing blob bba0871d6353dc62f105c757978d224f8c224c03
missing blob bb61249cfb3d2470572911b68d920abd77dcad2e
missing tree c481208829c1275cc4d5dd1ef316f2e2832234ca
missing blob c42147c58ad95201ec590f52b5a22ba08d4e942f
missing blob c44110ff88641d5c14327ca7b00f5a76ff8e2228
missing blob c442050c12d64c3f1dd21deb829314d824670f79
missing blob c405c0acde50fbcc3ba240b105d88fc18256a605
dangling tree 4ee8f71cec011177d057415ec822eae23225699a
missing blob c46859a5137b04e6342147b6780f927089ccb8e7
missing blob bb69d9a0778058e7a5c6f872846659189e998f25
missing blob bb6a64000c058a75dd86510a3f4e1fa4e9dfad04
missing blob bb2a3fc65c38168a96b6e2baae6b7adffa812597
missing blob bb0ba653563b50784ec57785e189246a75e51e8b
missing blob bbeb6d9170b74545a8a20ec11fd049a86d7f313e
missing tree c40b8ac97a9afa0893ac6f10324848eb3a4cc460
dangling tree 86ae2fdbbe7ab685b3cdbae5e64cebdb5ed1291f
missing blob bb8e58c88a6b86169d25a1b15ea6be5a8031d6f0
missing blob c44eed79d1a98f2fe65c5b1dd9deb86827624089
missing blob bbefc6516f82b1947610b46d1e84c394f9f0fe23
missing blob c4cff0e29bc5a7dcd62d6b17e91a0e24c5af5025
dangling tree 12b0136b8200c06530a040d3e262deaa69eaab9e
missing blob bb50cb721e30ea8759089e8dd37cb79728c58651
missing blob c430db086cc4d0881642e07d630352b83c0026cd
missing blob bbb1c50ed0a66a3291088beb722f652fa39f6285
missing blob c4d1be8a2f7c2b4411693b36ae9b9e9c3c7154ff
dangling tree 2cb3c703da2bb5267b8562a476fb8f19381fb178
missing blob bbf3812ff88b82555fb9dba5c88392757854929c
missing blob bb14ba97547dfd68af6c6eba3bbd74416b9d683f
missing blob bb345fdd2f7ab26ca7fa7ab714d3279e445ca934
missing blob c414cfafdf560f15f43b491224c596ffb9cecba3
dangling tree 4f16115df4ef7a2aa804ebfbd91d55319968b379
dangling tree 08572d6482cb634d304d4152679146d633e545a8
missing blob c457fb4c4ea3758bcf10599b7d93d6202e195d3e
missing blob bb98c60ea1b96a838fe497742b9223ccd97abcc5
missing blob bbb83d859655f7687f2a5fb224a6ce42de07fc24
missing blob c4d8534a7667a48dd2b098bf23f607d2d0899e33
missing tree bbb9d8714d49586842fb141e5c3da6fb7cc90488
missing blob c4998429d0471239ffc521a63514c56e3fd403b2
missing blob c4f9a0de974d02b95eca11fd93aeb85e6523e945
missing tree c4995cff4851c8577bf6702635c0f760b4f59627
missing tree bb3aacd59b6f876f7213a466c94a32d6e1049020
missing blob bb5a95e6a741ff71d40e57e3341ad9d47d1d6831
missing blob c45bf78c96a972a88d79d927a1fba5ade6b197b1
missing blob c41ca6b00b211068e825e9d8a720b1e8fa6ce590
dangling tree ce7d1fe488143f000ff098402695b8764326dc4c
```

Comment: Are you sure everything got copied?

Comment: By `re-checkout` do you mean `re-clone`? If things gotten broken internally, checking out again probably won't work. You could rename the main repo folder out of the way, clone again from a clean copy to where your renamed copy was, then copy your working files back over to that and be on your way again.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the complete checkout should be no problem. Somehow nevertheless your *.git* directory was corrupted.

If a new clone is not an option and you need to fix your repository, have a look at [the corresponding Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_to_fix_a_broken_repository.3F).